# Как запустить Сишный код из Python с правами суперпользователя?

Tags: python, c, django

У меня имеется сишная библиотека, которой я пользуюсь из *питона*. Взаимодействие по [этой схеме](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html).

Проблема вот в чем: процесс *python'а* работает с правами суперпользователя, но сишные функции из библиотеки, которые вызываются этим процессом, работают без прав суперпользователя, соответственно возвращают ошибку.

Как быть в этой ситуации?

**Update:** Работаю с *django*. Изначально пробовал запускать компилированные объектные файлы из питона - работает как нужно.

Но во `views.py` пробовал вызывать разными методами (например, [таким](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197509/redirecting-stdio-from-a-command-in-os-system-in-python)) — не вышло:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory

несмотря на то, что объектный файл лежит в одной директории с `views.py`.

Comment: как вы определяете, что «процесс python'а работает с правами суперпользователя» и «функции … работают без прав суперпользователя»? добавьте, пожалуйста, эту информацию в вопрос. заодно не помешало бы и указание используемой операционной системы.

Comment: Работаю в Raspbian на Raspberry PI. Файл запускаю `sudo python file.py`. Определил просто - запускал питоновский код, который вызывает сишный как с правами суперпользователя, так и без и получал многократно одинаковый результат ошибки.

Comment: Что означает "Сишный код" в Вашем вопросе? 1. `foo.so` файл, с `foo` модулем расширения для Питона, который просто импортируется: `import foo` 2. `libfoo.so` Сишная библиотека, которую Вы с помощью ctypes, cffi хотите использовать  3. `./foo` исполняемый файл, который можно запустить, используя `subprocess` модуль.

Answer (score 5):

> соответственно возвращают ошибку:
>
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory, несмотря на то, что объектный файл лежит в одной директории со views.py

ошибка не связана с отсутствием/наличием каких-то прав. вообще «дочерние» процессы (по умолчанию) наследуют привилегии от породившего их процесса.

ошибка вызвана тем, что у вас не *ms/windows*, а *gnu/linux*, и поиск библиотек (по умолчанию) не производится ни в текущем, ни в каком-либо другом **произвольном** каталоге.

можно попробовать добавить текущий каталог — `.` (или любой другой нужный) — к переменной окружения `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, например, так:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH python file.py
```

если же используется `sudo`, то, скорее всего команда вида:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH sudo python file.py
```

не даст эффекта — наверняка `sudo` в используемой системе сконфигурирован игнорировать `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` из переменных окружения, поэтому данную переменную программе `sudo` надо передавать явно при вызове как параметр:

```
$ sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH python file.py
```