# Путь к динамическим библиотекам

Tags: linux, unix

Как правильно указать путь к библиотекам?

Имеется бинарник `example`, который при запуске требует указать путь к библиотекам `libex.so`, `libamp.so`.
Нужно написать скрипт `script.sh`, в которому будут указаны пути к этим библиотекам.

Имеются подвиги, но кривые и неверные. Содержимое скрипта:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=libex:. libamp:.
./example
```

У меня полная каша в голове с этими путями.

Comment: ещё: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436482/178576

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/каталог/с/so-1:/каталог/с/so-2:/каталог/с/so-3
/home/neko69/bin/example
```

Файлы тут указывать не надо, только пути.

Comment: прошу прощения, не могли бы вы указать эту инструкцию для скрипта вызова example ?

Comment: См. обновление ответа

Comment: Что значат "с/so-1, /с/so-2" ?

Comment: `/каталог/с/so-1` означает каталог с первой из нужных сошек. Если такой каталог один  для всех библиотек, то остальные указывать не нужно. Ваш К.О.

Comment: что значит `/c` и зачем оно вообще нужно?

Comment: каталог_с_so. это русская c [https://www.lingq.com/learn/ru/preview/item/319979/] (-_-)

Comment: @pink-tux почему вы не написали `/каталог_с_so-1/` ? Я сижу и думаю, что это еще за подкаталоги такие странные